# NSView subclass - drawRect: not called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a `NSView` subclass called `DAView`, incorporating an array of useful methods for later re-use. This works great, however, `drawRect:` is never called in any classes that use `DAView`, nor in the class itself. Why?

Here's how `DAView` looks like:

**DAView**

`@interface DAView : NSView`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];

        // Make layer-backed by default
        self.wantsLayer = YES;

        // Create a root layer
        CALayer *_rootLayer = [CALayer layer];

        _rootLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;

        _rootLayer.name = DAViewRootLayerDefaultName;

        self.layer = _rootLayer;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect // never called
{
    NSLog(@"Draw Rect called");
}
```

Now, if I wanted to make use of this `DAView's` additions/methods, I face the same problem. Everything works fine, except for `drawRect:`, which, as in `DAView`'s case, is never called:

**DATableView**

`@interface DATableView : DAView`

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect // never called either
{
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];

    NSBezierPath *_cellSeparator = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

    [_cellSeparator lineToPoint:dirtyRect.origin];

    [_cellSeparator closePath];

    [_cellSeparator stroke];

    NSLog(@"Draw rect");
}
```

However If I change `DATableView`'s header to be a subclass of `NSView`, `drawRect:` is called.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set the delegate of `_rootLayer` to `self`.

**EDIT**
How it works for me:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
        self.layer = [self makeBackingLayer];
        [self.layer setDelegate:self];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    NSRect rect = self.bounds;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    [self drawRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: This makes no difference and I think it can't be the answer. `NSView`, unlike `UIView`, does not have the `wantsLayer` property set to `YES` by default and yet `drawRect:` is still called (except in my case for some reason), even without a layer as its backing store.

Comment: your drawrect is not called even without the layer backing? Than i think your problem does not show up in your code.

Comment: `drawRect:` is called without the layer backing - sorry! But with my layer, it's not...how can I combine the two?

Comment: I am not sure if this the correct way to it, but this is how i got it to work on OSX.

Comment: It does work. But `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` was the old way of doing it.  And it means you can't draw with the AppKit drawing API, due to some thread safety issues. These days `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect` does work properly even with CALayer.

Answer (score 11):

From the docs:

"The order that setWantsLayer: and setLayer: are called is important, it makes the distinction between a layer-backed view and a layer-hosting view."

"A layer-backed view is a view that is backed by a Core Animation layer. Any drawing done by the view is cached in the backing layer. You configure a layer-backed view by invoking setWantsLayer: with a value of YES. The view class automatically creates a backing layer for you (using makeBackingLayer if overridden), and you must use the view class’s drawing mechanisms. When using layer-backed views you should never interact directly with the layer. Instead you must use the standard view programming practices."

"A layer-hosting view is a view that contains a Core Animation layer that you intend to manipulate directly. You create a layer-hosting view by instantiating a Core Animation layer class and supplying that layer to the view’s setLayer: method. After doing so, you then invoke setWantsLayer: with a value of YES. This method order is crucial. When using a layer-hosting view you should not rely on the view for drawing, nor should you add subviews to the layer-hosting view. The root layer (the layer set using setLayer:) should be treated as the root layer of the layer tree and you should only use Core Animation drawing and animation methods. You still use the view for handling mouse and keyboard events, but any resulting drawing must be handled by Core Animation."

Since you are supplying your own layer, rather than wanting Cocoa to create one for you, try it this way around.

```
    // Create a root layer
    CALayer *_rootLayer = [CALayer layer];

    _rootLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;

    _rootLayer.name = DAViewRootLayerDefaultName;

    self.layer = _rootLayer;

    // Make layer-backed by default
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
```

Or alternatively, accept the one Cocoa gives you and don't create your own.