# drawRect not getting called for layer backed drawing with NSView

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview, metal

I am trying to migrate my Opengl application to Metal, and I am using `CAMetalLayer` for the Metal implementation.
I have set the following properties on my inherited `NSView` class object:

```
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize;
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

I have checked other answers on SO, like [NSView subclass - drawRect: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751441/nsview-subclass-drawrect-not-called)

So, I tried assigning the delegate as suggested in answers above, something like this

```
[self.layer setDelegate:self];
```

and I get the following compilation error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<CALayerDelegate> _Nullable' with an lvalue of type 'MyNSView *'
```

Moreover, I also see the documentation for setting up layer objects at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html, which states this:

> For layer-backed views with custom content, you should continue to
>   override the view’s methods to do your drawing. A layer-backed view
>   automatically makes itself the delegate of its layer and implements
>   the needed delegate methods, and you should not change that
>   configuration. Instead, you should implement your view’s drawRect:
>   method to draw your content.

So, according to this, I don't even have to set the delegate in my case and I am already implementing the `drawRect` function in `MyNSView`. Still it doesn't get called.

Is there anything more that needs to be done?

Thanks!

**Edit**:
So, I fixed the compilation error by making my layer follow the protocol `CALayerDelegate`, but still I don't get any calls to `drawLayer` or `drawRect`.

makeBackingLayer

```
- (CALayer*)makeBackingLayer
{
    id <MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    CAMetalLayer *backingLayer   = [CAMetalLayer layer];
    backingLayer.opaque          = YES;
    backingLayer.device          = device;
    backingLayer.pixelFormat     = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    backingLayer.framebufferOnly = YES;

//    [backingLayer setDelegate:self]; //Tried setting the delegate 
                                       //here as well

    return backingLayer;
}
```

init function

```
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize;
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.layer setDelegate:self];
```

Draw functions

```
- (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    [self drawRect:self.bounds];
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    [self drawRect:self.bounds];
}

-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

I have implemented all the draw functions to check if any of them get hit, but I don't receive a call on any of these functions.

For drawing content to the NSView, I draw to offscreen resources and the get the `drawable` from CALayer of NSView and call `presentDrawable` before committing on the `commandBuffer`.

Comment: Why aren't you using a subclass of `MTKView`? How did you arrange to use `CAMetalLayer` for the layer? Did you override `-makeBackingLayer`? If so, show that method and any place else you try to configure the layer.

Comment: @KenThomases It is a limitation to use NSView only for using Metal Rendering. And Yes, I am using `makeBackingLayer` to generate the layer. I'll update the question with relevant code snippets.

Comment: @KenThomases Updated details in question.

Comment: What other methods of `NSView` do you override? What other properties do you set on it? For example, do you override `-wantsUpdateLayer` to return true?

Comment: @KenThomases I have tried overriding `-wantsUpdateLayer` to return true, and then override `UpdateLayer`. But, apparently that doesn't get called. I also tried changing the `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` to `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay ` and calling `[nsView setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, after I call `commit` on the command buffer, but that doesn't seem to trigger drawing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there wasn't much here that I could debug to find where the bug was introduced, so I started playing with the order in which the instructions were executed. And as it turns out, the order in which you call :

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize;
```

was causing the issue. On swapping these two statements, I started receiving call to my `displayLayer` function. I still couldn't figure out why `drawRect` doesn't get called for layer backed NSView.

Posting this just in case this swapping fixes the issue for someone else as well.

Comment: Note that if your `CALayerDelegate` class implements both `-displayLayer:` and `-drawLayer:inContext:`, then only the former will be called.